# Django Form not raising ValidationError

Tags: django, django-forms

I am having a Django form, that I try to validate against two values that I compare.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    if cleaned_data['preferred_communication'] == 'email' and cleaned_data['email']:
        pass
    else:
        print('error error error')
        raise ValidationError(_('Please type in your email address, if you want to be notified.'))
```

I see the print output in my command line, so the logic works.
Still the form.is_valid seems to be True.

Comment: Where are you importing `ValidationError` from?

Comment: from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

Comment: Try attaching it to the field, given that you're trying to validate the data in the form. `forms.ValidationError({"some_field": "raise an error"})`

Comment: Code seems correct, attaching to form should not be necessary. Have you tried raising the error without using gettext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, the form.is_valid() worked, but no exception was caugt in the view.

Always have an ELSE in if form.is_valid().

Answer (score -1):

So, basically I think you just need to make your validation function to be completed. I see in [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validation-error) that even if your clean function doesn't do anything except for field validation you still need to return the original value in this method.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    if cleaned_data['preferred_communication'] == 'email' and cleaned_data['email']:
        return cleaned_data
    else:
        print('error error error')
        raise ValidationError(_('Please type in your email address, if you want to be notified.'))
```